# Is it possible to view a user's certificate store while signed in as a different user? Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, jenkins, windows, certificate

I'm currently migrating a Jenkins server and I need to install a certificate on the new machine for some of my builds.  The problem is I'm not sure on which store to use and no one remembers the password of the account that Jenkins ran under on the old server.

I'd like to avoid resetting the password of this account on our prod server so I've been searching for a way to view a user's certificate store without actually being logged in as that user.

I've been using MMC to view certificates but it doesn't appear to be possible to look at the stores of other users.  At least not intuitively.  Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you can not reset the password, you can try another way of authentication. E.g. if you have PKI and smart cards, you can issue a smart card for this account. Probably an overkill, but it will work.